# JQUERY iterate with array

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help for my website. I'm trying to iterate with an array and two different input field.
my html file contains like below:

```
<input name="comune" type="text" id="comune" list="comuni" />
<datalist id="comuni">
</datalist>
<input name="provincia" type="text" id="provincia" />
```

Let's say that my array is like this:

```
    var comProv = {
    'Pisa' : 'PI',
    'Firenze' = 'FI',
    'Roma' = 'RM'}
```

I would like to populate the datalist with the Key of the array and, on selection of specific option, I would like to show in the second input field the value of the same array?s item.

I tried with this code

```
    $('#comune').keyup(function(){
        var options = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < comProv.length; i++){
            options += '<option value="'+comProv[i]+'" />';
        }
        document.getElementById('comuni').innerHTML = options;
    });
```

I stopped without moving to the second topic cause I'm stack. Anyone can help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `for...in` loop

Comment: ok I will try now

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: I'm totally new in programming (I'm not a programmer but a lawyer) that's why for me is not so easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not an array, it is an object. Second, you need to use "for...in" loop to loop object or $.each if you are using jQuery library. Last but not least, you have typo error in your object. Finally, try this code that is in this snippet:

```js
$(function(){

    var comProv = {
        'Pisa' : 'PI',
        'Firenze':'FI',
        'Roma': 'RM'
    }

    $('#comune').keyup(function(){
        var options = '';
        $.each(comProv, function(key, value) {
            options += `<option value="${value}">${key}</option>`;
        });
        $('#comuni').html(options);
    });


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="comune" type="text" id="comune" list="comuni" />
<datalist id="comuni">
</datalist>
<input name="provincia" type="text" id="provincia" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. About the second question...I need to put the key in the on keyup in the first input and the value in the second input field. Is it possible? then I will disappear :)

Comment: so in first input it should be Pisa for example and in the second Input P1?

Comment: but what if they will again put the cursor on the second input?))) you value will change then, it is no good

Comment: I'm evaluating or to substitute with a label or anyway I want to make the second input "readonly"

Comment: use $('#inputId').prop('readonly', true); to make it readonly)

Comment: ok but how to change the value of the second input with the selected key of the first inout? I mean I select from the datalist a key, the corresponding value I would like to go in the second input

Comment: @S.Iandolo I need a bit more details/code example to answer your question

Comment: if you take the html code at the beginning, you will see that the input fields are 2. In the first the user will select an element from the datalist for which you already helped me. So the datalist is populated by the keys of the object. When the user will select one of the element i.e. from the list the user will select Firenze. In the #comune input will appear Firenze and in the #provincia input field should appera FI

Comment: maybe i solved with this code: $('#comune').select(function(){
     var comune = $('#comune').val();
     $.each(comProv, function( key, value) {
      var x = `${key}`;
      if (x === comune){
       $('#provincia').val(`${value}`);
      }     
  });
    })

Comment: @S.Iandolo if it works for you, then you solved it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's an object, not an array. You can iterate it using `$.each()`.

```
$('#comune').keyup(function(){
    var options = '';
    $.each(comProv, function(key, value) {
        options += `<option value="${value}">${key}</option>`;
    });
    $('#comuni').html(options);
});
```

Comment: Thank to you also very much